# how to submit form when preventDefault() is being used?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i have a form and i have tried to implement tinuy jquery ajax code it it.
but the problem is i used preventDefault() to stop form from auto submitting. Now i cant make it submit even when i want it to.

```
//after user clicks submit buttons
    $('.submit').click(function(event){
        data =  {
                    country: $('.country').val(),
                    tel_country_code: $('.country_code').val(),
                    tel_no: $('.tel_no').val()
                }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo site_url('listings/does_business_exists');?>",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(json_data){
                    if(json_data.result == false){
                        $('.error-position').html(json_data.errors);
                        $('.error-position').show();
                    }
                    else{
                        return true;
//i want form to submit here

                    }

            }

        });

        event.preventDefault();
    })
```

any suggestion friends ??

Comment: Thank u all for suggestions but i figured it out the another way. Thank u again

Comment: if you figured it out another way, please include your solution, so that others looking for a similar solution will know what you did to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Just get the form and submit it

```
document.forms["formName"].submit();
```

Comment: What error do you get? Check your console, or firebug, if you're using firefox. Did you remember to switch out "formName" with the name of your form? And did you set the `name` attribute on your form? If I remember correctly, the `document.forms[]` doesn't work with `id`

Comment: It does work, and you can even switch out `[]` with dot notation. Working example here: http://jsbin.com/aniyav/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.submit').click(function(event){
    var $this = $(this);

    data =  {
                country: $('.country').val(),
                tel_country_code: $('.country_code').val(),
                tel_no: $('.tel_no').val()
            }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo site_url('listings/does_business_exists');?>",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json_data){
                if(json_data.result == false){
                    $('.error-position').html(json_data.errors);
                    $('.error-position').show();
                }
                else{
                    $this.parents('form:first').trigger('submit');
                }

        }

    });

    return false;
})
```

Comment: It's async, so that `return false` will be called waaay to late.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... The event.preventDefault is currently outside of the ajax request, so it will be called instantaneously

Comment: But he can't check the validity of the form until the AJAX returns, which will be on a separate thread by then, and it will always be true.

Comment: I just realized you're clicking a submit button, not submitting the actual form. I've updated my code to something that should work for you

Comment: sorry! this one didnot work either

Comment: Is your button with a class of submit, inside of the actual form being submitted?

Answer (score 0):

add like this, traverse the document, get the form object, and then call the submit method on it. check this link [Document.forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLFormElement)

```
var obj= document.forms["yourForm"];
    obj.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `event.preventDefault();` and try:

```
<form onsubmit = "return false;"> ... </form>
```

Comment: That will make it impossible to ever submit the form. :\

Comment: @peirix that is what he wants. He wants to use ajax to submit the form.

Comment: No, he's using ajax to validate the form, then if it's valid he wants to submit it.